# Unable to change OpenID to StackExchange OpenID

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-exchange, openid, authentication

I'm trying to change my primary OpenID ( on my Super User account) from MyOpenID to Stack Exchange. Went over to my profile, clicked on "Change OpenID", and selected Login with Stack Exchange. Instead of logging in, I got the below error message:

> Could Not Find Pending Authentication
> Request
>
> We were unable to find the
> pending authentication request, and
> cannot resume login.
>
> If you believe you encountered this
> message in error, please report it.

---

Trying to login again using StackExchage OpenID, I get only a "login" button, followed by "Page not found"

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: This looks like the problem I got - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91039/help-us-test-and-vet-stackid-stack-exchange-openid/92217#92217 (10K+ only I'm afraid) but couldn't repeat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error should be fixed now.

We had a settings kerfuffle, that basically broke all forms everywhere on `openid.stackexchange.com`.  Our apologies.

Comment: thanks @Kevin, was able to change.

Comment: So are stackexchange openids still able to be changed?  I am accessing [openid.stackexchange.com](http://openid.stackexchange.com/) but I am unable to find this functionality?